# How do I list (ls) the content of a folder/directory recursively but to a depth of only one folder/directory?

Tags: ls

How do I list (ls) the content of a folder/directory recursively but to a depth of only one folder/directory?

I have the following folder structure:

```
folderA:
  folderB1:
    folderC1:
      fileD1:
      fileD2:
    fileC2
    fileC3
  folderB2:
    folderC4:
      fileD3:
      fileD4:
    fileC5
    fileC6
```

I am in the parent folder of `folderA` and would like to list everything in it and its subfolders but not subsubfolders. So I would like to see:

```
folderB1/folderC1
folderB1/fileC2
folderB1/fileC3
folderB2/folderC2
folderB2/fileC4
folderB2/fileC5
```

Is that possible? At the moment, I use `ls -R folderA` which takes me down a rabbit hole of hundreds of subsub..subfolders I am not interested in. I would like to stop at a certain depth. Ideally, there would be an option like `depth 1` to list the content of folderA and its subfolders and stop.

I am working on macOS X High Sierra.

Comment: should folderC4 be folderC2? and should fileC4 in the output be fileC6?

Comment: `man find` search for `--maxdepth`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want a *recursive* listing, then, because as you've seen, recursive means "to the end", not "to some arbitrary stopping point".

To list two levels beneath folderA while in folderA's parent,

```
(cd folderA && ls -d -- */*)
```

The crux of it is the `*/*` wildcard/glob; that asks the shell to generate all of the immediate subdirectories (with `*/`) and then all of its entries (the final `*`).

Importantly, we have to tell `ls` to *not* expand any of those final entries if they happen to be directories; we do this with the `-d` flag.

The last piece, to get the output format you're looking for, I solved by starting a subshell where we `cd` into folderA in order to do the listing. Once `ls` exits, the subshell exits, and we return to our current prompt & directory (above folderA).